# QQ plot looks like gaussian, but kolmogorov smirnov test suggests to reject null hypothesis

Tags: normal-distribution, python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, qq-plot

I am testing my estimation of maximum likelihood parameters using the normal equation for gaussian generalised linear model. I am trying 3 covariates and 4 parameters (i.e. includingintercept) and in m present run have 500 samples of 10,000 observations. I am using the statsmodels library to generate a qq plot and run the KS normal test for each of my 4 parameters.

To my eye, all QQ plots look Gaussian, and pretty much the same. However I get p values of 0.2, 0.2, 0.166, 0.00197. So there is something funny going on with the last estimate. Here is the QQ plot for the 4th parameter:

[image: Parameter 4]

And for parameters 1,2,3 for reference:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

**Does anyone know what may be happening?**

Another question that is related, but let me know if more appropriate to relegate to another post:

1. **I seem to consistently get** 2, 3, or 4 of my parameters having **p value of 0.2**. Now I have even changed the parameter values to 200 observations of 1000 sample sizes, and still I get 0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2 (without any decimals). In fact, now reducing my covariaate numbers to 1 and then 0, I still keep getting 0.2 with the odd value not 0.2!I think this is highly suspect, as this should be a statistic. *I have put my code below if anyone asks.*

Data generating:

```
#Function to ouptput n observations of: p random normally distributed covariate values
#(alter the distribution in the function), and the corresponding n y endogenous (dependent) values
#for standard gaussian GLM. Input: number of observations n, number of covariates p, and the true (p+1)
#parameter values (i.e. with intercept).

import numpy as np

def gaussian_data(n,p, beta):
    #Define parameters

    #1)Number of covariates
    p_i = p+1           #with intercept
    p_i=np.int(p_i)

    #2) m as correct data type
    n=np.int(n)

    #3)Link function
    def g(z):
        return z

    #4)Specify parameter valueas to be estimated
    beta=np.reshape(beta, (p_i,1))

    #5)Define distribution from which covariate values are drawn i.i.d., and initiate data values
    mean=0
    sigma=0.5
    X=np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(n,p_i))
    X[:,0]=1    #intercept




    #6)Specify Gaussian error distribution for data values y
    eta=np.asarray(np.random.normal(0,0.2,n))
    eta=np.reshape(eta, (n,1))


    #7)Produce data values
    y=g(X.dot(beta))+eta

    return X, y
```

Main code:

```
#Script for producing y data from p covariates from a specified distribution, specified beta paraemters,
#and n data samples for gaussian function.

import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.stats as sms
import statsmodels.api as sm
from gaussian_data import gaussian_data
from gaussian_normal_equation import normalEquationGaussian



#1)Sample numbers to test for erros in beta, as powers of 10.
samples=200
n_obs = 1000

#2)Number of independent covariates
p=0

#3)True beta to be estimated (parameter values)
beta=np.asarray([1.8])



#4)#Initiate arrays for estimates of beta (and errors) at specified sample numbers in vector n
Betas=np.zeros((samples,p+1))
covLimBetas=np.zeros((samples,p+1))
Errors=np.zeros((samples,p+1))

#5)Obtain random covariate values from specified distribution, and corresponding y values using true beta
#plus gaussian noise term.

for i in range(samples):
    X,y = gaussian_data(n_obs,p,beta)
    betaTemp=normalEquationGaussian(X,y)
    Betas[i,:] = np.reshape(betaTemp,p+1)

for i in range(p+1):
    pf = sms.diagnostic.kstest_normal(Betas[:,i]) 

    print('normal diagnostic ks test for parameter beta %s' %(i+1), pf)

    sm.qqplot(Betas[:,i], line='q')
    pylab.savefig('QQplot%s.png' %(i+1))
    pylab.show()


for i in range(p+1):
    plt.hist(Betas[:,i], bins=30)

    plt.show()


#7)Calculate true erros 
Errors=Betas-beta.transpose()
absError=np.abs(Errors)
#nerror=Errors*np.sqrt(n)[:,np.newaxis]
meanstd=np.zeros((2,len(beta)))

print(Betas)

meanstd[0,:] =  np.mean(Betas, axis=0)
meanstd[1,:] =  np.std(Betas, axis=0)

print(meanstd)
```

Comment: The plots you show display only 1,000 observations each, not 10,000.

Comment: @whuber No. The plots are from 10,000 observations, 500 samples. The code I have provided (that says 200 samples, 1000 obs) is after I adjusted the covariate number and the observation/sample number to see the effect of changing these... unless you are using some other way to determine the number of obs in the plot figures, and not just what is written in the code.